# How do you combine IF, AND and NOT statements in Microsoft excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to compare `Column A` and `Column B` with `Column C` and `Column D` and display the results in `Column E` as shown in the table below using the following formula:

[image: Excel Table]

```
=IF(NOT(IF(AND(A2=C2,B2=D2),"Names Correct","Names Not Correct")),AND(NOT(A2=C2),B2=D2),"Car Worng, Driver Correct", "Car Correct, Driver Wrong")
```

But I get the error when I press enter:

```
You've Entered too many arguments for this function
```

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Eidt: forgot to include table.

Answer (score 1):

If you indent your code, you'll see that it doesnt really match up.

```
=IF(
  NOT(
    IF(
      AND(
        A2=C2,
        B2=D2
      ),
      "Names Correct",
      "Names Not Correct"
    )
  ),
  AND(
    NOT(
      A3=C3
    ),
    B3=D3
  ),
  "Car Worng, Driver Correct", 
  "Car Correct, Driver Wrong"
)
```

You have a `IF(NOT, AND, value1, value2)` at the top level.
I dont know what your goal was, but hopefully this helps you solve it.

Comment: My goal is to compare `Column A` with `Column C` , and `Column B`  with `Column D` and to display the desired results as shown in `Column E` using a formula. I'm confused on how to do this combining `IF`, `AND, and `NOT` statements. I'm not sure if this is the right approach or if there's an easier method.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `NOT`, the required result can be achieved using nested `IF` statements and the `AND` function

```
=IF(AND(A2=C2,B2=D2),"Names Correct",IF(AND(A2=C2,B2<>D2),"Car Correct, Driver Wrong",IF(AND(A2<>C2,B2=D2),"Car Wrong , Driver Correct","Names Not Correct")))
```

Or formatted a bit better.

```
=IF(AND(A2=C2,B2=D2),"Names Correct",
 IF(AND(A2=C2,B2<>D2),"Car Correct, Driver Wrong",
 IF(AND(A2<>C2,B2=D2),"Car Wrong , Driver Correct",
  "Names Not Correct")))
```